# Improving the reading and join of multiple spark datasets in parquet

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have to read multiple datasets of around 5 gigs each. Each directoryPath contains more than 30 files.The method I have of reading them is using the command below and transform into some mapping.

```java
 Dataset<T> DatasetA = spark.read.parquet(directoryPath).as(Encoders.bean(someMapping));
```

This happens for multiple files > 15 and later I join them together based on a common `key`.

I have a scenario in here wherein to improve performance there is another file ex `LesserDataFileDataset` that can be joined on to reduce the amount of data I am processing in the end.

I persist `LesserDataFileDataset` first so I don't read it again and again.
I tried 2 approaches to improve the way this functions.

1. I join each of the above Datasets with the `LesserDataFileDataset`.
   This yields me `DatasetA`, `DatasetB`...etc. with fewer data.
   After this, I perform the join operations on all of these datasets

```java
DatasetA
.join(DatasetB.drop(Common key to select only from DatasetA),ColumnToJoin)
.join(DatasetC.drop(Common key to select only from DatasetA),ColumnToJoin)
```

2. In a second path, I tried to join the datasets together at the end with
   `LesserDataFileDataset` like below:

```java
LesserDataFileDataset.
 .join(DatasetA,ColumnToJoinSequenceWithOneColumn,"left-outer")
.join(DatasetB,ColumnToJoinSequenceWithOneColumn,"left-outer")
.join(DatasetC,ColumnToJoinSequenceWithOneColumn,"left-outer")
```

This yields me similar performance while reading and joining.

Another way I tried to improve performance is by reading `file1` of `DatasetA`,  `file1` of `DatasetB` ... and then join it with the `LesserDataFileDataset` in a manner similar to the 2 methods above. This had a detrimental effect whereby the performance actually went down. Can someone help.